# Switching back in tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have three tabs with a pageviewer and actionbar bar. When I try to switch back to a tab that was already selected, no data is shown, but the logcat indicates that data was pulled from the server and add in the arraylist.

Any suggestions as to why the data will not show now? I have done extensive research and still fail to understand what is happening.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_tabs);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Log.v("Main-onCreate-viewPager", viewPager.toString());
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
            Log.v("Main", "tab added");
        }


        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         **/
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                Log.v("onPageScrolled-position", Integer.toString(position));
                Log.v("onPageScrolled-position", Float.toString(positionOffset));
                Log.v("onPageScrolled-position", Integer.toString(positionOffsetPixels));
            }

            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                Log.v("onPageSelected", "onPageSelected");
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                Log.v("onPageSelected-position", Integer.toString(position));
        }


            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                Log.v("StateChanged", "OnPageScrollStateChanged");
                Log.v("statechanged-state", Integer.toString(state));

            }
        });
    }
   public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Log.v("Main", "Tab REselected");
            Log.v("onTabReselected", tab.toString());
            Log.v("onTabReselected", ft.toString());

            if(tab.getPosition() == 0){
                Log.v("onTabReselected", "ImagesFragment");
                Fragment frag;
                FragmentManager fm1 = Main.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm1.beginTransaction();
                frag = new ImagesFragment();
                //frag = new FeaturesFragment();
                ft1.replace(R.id.pager, frag);
                ft1.commit();
                frag.setUserVisibleHint(true);
            }

            if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                Log.v("onTabReselected", "FeaturesFragment");
                Fragment frag;
                FragmentManager fm1 = Main.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm1.beginTransaction();
                frag = new FeaturesFragment();
                ft1.replace(R.id.pager, frag);
                ft1.commit();
                frag.setUserVisibleHint(true);

            }

            if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
                Log.v("onTabReselected", "OptionsFragment");
                Fragment frag;
                FragmentManager fm1 = Main.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm1.beginTransaction();
                frag = new OptionsFragment();
                ft1.replace(R.id.pager, frag);
                ft1.commit();
                frag.setUserVisibleHint(true);

            }
        }

        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // on tab selected
            // show respected fragment view
            Log.v("onTabSelected", tab.toString());
            Log.v("onTabSelected", ft.toString());
            Log.v("tab position1", Integer.toString(tab.getPosition()));
            viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
            //viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition()); //null pointer exception here
            tab.select(); //no null pointer exception, but no show data when swiping tabs
            Log.v("onTabSelected", tab.toString());

            Log.v("tab position", Integer.toString(tab.getPosition()));

             if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {

                Fragment frag;
                FragmentManager fm1 = Main.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm1.beginTransaction();
                 frag = new ImagesFragment();
                ft1.replace(R.id.pager, frag);
                ft1.commit();
                frag.setUserVisibleHint(true);
            }

                if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {

                    Fragment frag;
                    FragmentManager fm1 = Main.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm1.beginTransaction();
                    frag = new FeaturesFragment();
                    ft1.replace(R.id.pager, frag);
                    ft1.commit();
                    frag.setUserVisibleHint(true);

                }

                if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
                    Fragment frag;
                    FragmentManager fm1 = Main.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm1.beginTransaction();
                    frag = new OptionsFragment();
                    ft1.replace(R.id.pager, frag);
                    ft1.commit();
                    frag.setUserVisibleHint(true);

                }
            }


        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Log.v("Main", "Tab UNselected");
            Log.v("onTabUnselected", tab.toString());
            Log.v("onTabUnselected", ft.toString());
     }




public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        Log.v("index", Integer.toString(index));
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                Log.v("TabsPagerAdapter", "case 0: ImagesFragment");
                return new ImagesFragment();
            case 1:
                Log.v("TabsPagerAdapter", "case 1: FeaturesFragment");
                return new FeaturesFragment();
            case 2:
                Log.v("TabsPagerAdapter", "case 2: OptionsFragment");
                return new OptionsFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did u try my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Use FragmentStatePagerAdapter in place of TabsPagerAdapter.

Comment: Please elaborate. I have a class named TabsPagerAdapter that extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Code for it is posted above now.

Comment: hey you are returning null in your getItem method.

Comment: Yes, null when none of the tabs were properly selected. I cannot re-select tabs (go back to a tab that was already selected and loaded). I am NOT getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: why are you making this code so complex what do you want to do??

Comment: I want to select between three tabs (which are fragments and each have different data and layouts) in a view both forward and backward.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you i also had this problem i have 4 tabs and switching them re creates the view, after setting adapter use this code,

```
viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5); //this one.!
```

Any number of limit you can have but better to have low numbers because of memory customization, use it inside oncreate() method(if Activity).